How to display multi level array data from a collection?
I need to display a list of values from a collection.
I have a collection with the following values:
[
  {
    "Items": [
      {
        "Key": "Key1",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Value": "Value 1",
            "EndDT": "2024-01-31T15:43:53.000Z"
          },
          {
            "Value": "Value 2",
            "EndDT": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "Key2",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Value": "Value 3",
            "EndDT": "2024-01-31T15:43:53.000Z"
          },
          {
            "Value": "Value 4",
            "EndDT": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Items": [
      {
        "Key": "Key1",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Value": "Value 5",
            "EndDT": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "Key4",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Value": "Value 3",
            "EndDT": "2024-01-31T15:43:53.000Z"
          },
          {
            "Value": "Value 4",
            "EndDT": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

I need the results when I retrieve the collection using aggregation:
{
        $match: {
            'Items': {
                $elemMatch: {
                    'Key': 'Key1',
                    'Values': {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            'EndDT': null
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

The results should look like this:
[
  {
    "Items": [
      {
        "Key": "Key1",
        "Values": [
           {
              "Value": "Value 2",
              "EndDT": null
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Items": [
      {
        "Key": "Key1",
        "Values": [
           {
              "Value": "Value 5",
              "EndDT": null
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

I need to display the values within the items where Values EndDT is null.
This is an autogenerated reply

This question is similar to: Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Even if using $elemMatch like that worked, you'd get the outer element only, which would include the values having non-null dates for "EndDT".
To get the matching array "Items" AND only the matching sub-array for "Items.Value":

Unwind Items, then unwind Values
Do the $match for Key and EndDT
Put them back together with $group, once for Values and then Key.

The only requirement here is that each Item's Key should be unique. Otherwise, during the $group, they would be in the same "Values" array:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "Items.Key": "Key1"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$Items" },
  { $unwind: "$Items.Values" },
  {
    $match: {
      "Items.Key": "Key1",
      "Items.Values.EndDT": null
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        Key: "$Items.Key"
      },
      Values: { $push: "$Items.Values" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      Items: {
        $push: {
          Key: "$_id.Key",
          Values: "$Values"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
